# error: file stata.sty not found

Tags: packages, installing

I'm trying to manually install the [package sjlatex](http://www.stata-journal.com/author/). It's a package to write documents in the Stata Journal style and it's not part of any repository so I cannot install it via the MiKTeX package manager. I have put all the files that come with the package in

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\texmf\tex\latex\sjlatex
```

refreshed FNDB and updated format files. But when I run a simple document that calls up the `stata` package, I get the error message that `stata.sty` cannot be found, even though I can see `stata.sty` in

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\texmf\tex\latex\sjlatex
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stata}
\begin{document}

An example:

\begin{stlog}
\input{example2_1.log.tex}
\end{stlog}

\end{document}
```

`stlog` is an environment specified by the `stata` package, but I don't even get that far before the error message hits. I'm on Windows Vista and running MiKTeX 2.9 in WinEdt.

Also, I checked the file dependencies listed [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/author/) and, as far as I can tell, I have correctly installed all the required files (using the MiKTeX package manager).

I was hoping someone would have an idea of things I could try? Sorry if there is something obvious that I have missed ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I cleaned up your question a bit, hope you don't mind. As for your problem: Whenever I installed a package manually on MiKTeX, the name of the folder would be the same as the .sty package file, so in your case `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\texmf\tex\latex\stata` instead of `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\texmf\tex\latex\sjlatex`. I'm not sure this is the source of your problem, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Here's another alternative. Since the packages (`*.sty`) and class (`*.cls`) do not form part of a traditional LaTeX distribution, you could leave all the files (`statapress.cls`, `pagedims.sty`, `sj.sty` and `stata.sty`) in your *working folder* without updating your FNDB; LaTeX will search in the working folder first before moving on to the FNDB.

Comment: doncherry - thanks for editing the question and for the suggestion. I tried, both by putting all files that come with the package in a folder called stata, or only the `stata.sty` file. Still doesn't work, I'm afraid. Werner - putting the files in the local folder does the trick, thanks! It's not massively elegant, but it works for now.

Comment: For future readers: I added an explanation on how to link stata and LaTeX, see the linked question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448482/117274

Answer (score 3):

Since the packages (`*.sty`) and class (`*.cls`) do not form part of a traditional LaTeX distribution, you could leave all the files (`statapress.cls`, `pagedims.sty`, `sj.sty` and `stata.sty`) in your working folder without updating your FNDB; LaTeX will search in the working folder first before moving on to the FNDB.

There should be no concern with doing things this way, since the `sjlatex` bundle does not form part of any distribution. Consequently, you'll have to manually update the bundle if there is ever a newer version, and just overwrite the existing files in your working folder.